# Is it bad practice to add an entry to a table like so using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-deadlocks

I'm new to Entity Framework and was wondering if my code is considered bad practice and whether or not it could lead to deadlock.

```
var context = new DatabaseEntities();
var demoTable = new DemoTable();
var newEntry = context.demoTable.Create();

newEntry.Message = "Test message";
newEntry.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

if (addEntryToTable(context, demoTable, newLine))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Table updated.");
}
```

my function :

```
private bool addEntryToTable (DatabaseEntities context, System.Data.Entity.DbSet demoTable, Object newLine)
{
    try
    {
        demoTable.Add(newLine);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        demoTable.Remove(newLine);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the lock, why do you think that the add fails but the remove will always succeed then?

Comment: I was assuming that the add might succeed and the `context.SaveChanges();` might fail @TimSchmelter.

Comment: Yes, but then your 2nd `SaveChanges` might also fail, which is not wrapped in a `try...catch`. So either use one for both or handle the exception(s) at a higher layer. I would not remove the item in error case at all. This can lead to other issues. This method is suppoed to add something, not remove.